# Storage of data about the operations performed on a object in java

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String file = "C:\\Users\\RaviKiran Reddy\\Desktop\\JBNR\\NewBankAccounts.csv";
    List<String[]> newAccounts = Csv.read(file);
    List<Account> opaccounts = new LinkedList<Account>();
    for (String[] accountholdersdata : newAccounts) {
        String name = accountholdersdata[0];
        String ssn = accountholdersdata[1];
        String acctype = accountholdersdata[2];
        double initialDeposit = Double.parseDouble(accountholdersdata[3]);
        if (acctype == "Checking") {
            opaccounts.add(new Checking(name, ssn, acctype, initialDeposit));
        }
        else {
            opaccounts.add(new Savings(name, ssn, acctype, initialDeposit));
        }
    }
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("records.txt"));
    out.writeObject(opaccounts);
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("records.txt"));
    LinkedList<Account> a = new LinkedList<Account>();
    a = (LinkedList<Account>) in.readObject();
}
```

I wanted to build a real world bank application, so I stored the objects in a ".txt" file with the help of `LinkedList` and `ObjectOutputStream`. But the problem is whenever I perform operations on a object and close the project, and after when I again open the project and try to retrieve the data, the data regarding the previous operations is not being stored.

How to overcome this and store each and every operation performed on the objects?

Comment: Consider using a database instead of text files.

Comment: *a real world bank application. so I stored the objects in a ".txt" file with the help of LinkedList and ObjectOutputStream.* you made my day :-) We can't help you find where the problem is in your code if you don't post your code. We can't see your screen.

Comment: Who’s “we”? I, for one, can see his screen :p

Comment: i have added it @ JB Nizet

Comment: It's barely readable because it's not indented. But read your code: it always starts by writing to the file, and then reads what it just wrote. So of course, if you restart the app, it ill start by overwriting the content of the file, and not read what the previous execution wrote.

Comment: There are some problems with your code. In Java, we follow the Java Naming Conventions, that means that variable names are written in camelCase (starting with lowercase, and no underscores). Second, you are mixing arrays and `List`s, which is discouraged. Third, you are comparing strings with the `==` operator. You should [use the `equals` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: if you want to store stuff in a file I suggest XML instead of text. Then you can search and add stuff to it. a little more overhead of course..

Comment: ok, but could you explain how to stop overwriting and get what I wanted(to store the operations performed on the object) @ JB Nizet

Comment: Do not use standard deserialization. Do implement your own.

Comment: I don't  exactly know what is meant by own deserialization is. Could you tell me what it is @ oleg cherednik

Answer (score -1):

You need to close or flush "out" the object before reading it again immediately. And better use hashmap for key-value mapping for such database

```
 ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new 
 FileOutputStream("records.txt"));
 out.writeObject(opaccounts);
 out.close(); // use this or flush()
```

Comment: if we close the file using out.close, how can we write anything to the file again!!

Comment: if we close the file using out.close how can we write to the file again, because the link to the file gets collapsed if we run out.close.

Comment: I mentioned close or flush, it’s depends on your use case if you want to write it again with same object. Better use flush then read back